# Core Plot CPTAxisLabel - Height

Tags: core-plot, cptbarplot

I'm using core plot for plotting a bar chart. 
There i'm using custom labels (CPTAxisLabel) for X-Axis labels.
Some of my labels are long in length. In such cases, labels are not getting wrapped to next lines.

How can i achieve it in CPTAxisLabel ?

-Balaji R.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert newline (`'\n'`) characters in any text in Core Plot to force it to wrap to the next line. Use the `textAlignment` property of the text style to control the alignment (left, center, right) of the lines of text.

Comment: Thanks Eric. It works if i insert "\n" in the text. Also, Is there any way to specify it in generic way similar to UILabel's no.of.lines property ?  Because, In this approach we need to insert newline characters between words for each label.